I am making a coin, and need help baking
I am making a coin for a videogame me and my friend are making in Roblox, and I have made a coin, using a single material with nodes that include the image texture, and the generated gold material. Every time i try to bake, it comes out wrong. I need help.
[

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

nvm, I just had to bake without metallic on, and then used a white square for the metallic map, as I had it set to 1.
